# How to put an inline comma in markdown?

Tags: markdown, graphql, gatsby

In markdown how can I put a comma without it counting as code. I should add that this is in the variable section of the markdown page.

Example:

```
array: [
  line one without comma,
  line with comma here, still the same line,
  new line
]
```

So if I were to loop through this I get something like:

```
line one without comma
line with comma here
still the same line
new line
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Commas have no special meaning in Markdown. Perhaps you could edit your question to include the actual HTML output and the output you would like.

Comment: I want to be able to put a comma in the string here. but this creates 4 different strings for this array.

Comment: Markdown does not understand and run code. There is no such thing as an `array`. Are you perhaps using something else on top of Markdown (like r)?

Comment: I am using this with gatsbyjs and graphql. I query it and I have access through to this array if I grab the variable. You are right though I may need to delete this question or re write it.

Comment: can you split by "\n" or "\r" ? Otherwise, could you escape the regular comma? `line with comma here\, still the same line,` or similar

Comment: @KYL3R the \ puts a literal \ in the line so I don't think that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with it for a while and trying a lot of different things I just tried wrapping the lines in " " and it ended up working. So if you want to include a comma as part of the array string element you just do it like so:

```
array: [
  line one without comma,
  "line with comma here, still the same line",
  new line
]
```

My new output looks like:

```
line one without comma
line with comma here, still same line
new line
```